# What is std::__scan_keyword?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, c++-chrono

I'm looking for simply library for human likely `std::chrono` input/output. And I've found one - [chrono_io](https://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_io.html). Output works fine. But input don't work.
I got compile time error `error: ‘__scan_keyword’ was not declared in this scope`. What is `__scan_keyword`?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include "chrono_io" // https://howardhinnant.github.io/duration_io/chrono_io

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::string from = "42 ms";
  std::stringstream ss(from);
  std::chrono::steady_clock::duration to;
  ss >> to;
  return 0;
}
```

How can I compile this example?

I'm use compile command `g++-6 -c -m64 -std=c++14 main.cpp`

```
$ g++-6 -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++-6
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 6.1.1-4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-6 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.1.1 20160519 (Debian 6.1.1-4)
```

Comment: Please only post this in one place.  It is frowned upon to post this on multiple SE sites. [cross post](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532597/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-std-scan-keyword)

Comment: Try giving an MCVE and identifying your compiler (and standard library).   All identifiers starting with double `_` are reserved identifiers according to all C++ standards.   So `__scan_keyword` is an implementation detail that is specific to your your compiler (and/or library).    Therefore nobody will be able to help you, given only partial code and no information about what compiler and library you are using.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I'm sorry if a'm wrong. But sometimes some questions is very difficult for http://ru.stackoverflow.com/ Please see my other question. It's also duplicated. I've got answer here but on ru.stackoverflow.com don't.

Comment: @Peter - identifiers **containing** two consecutive underscores are reserved; not just beginning with. Not that it affects this particular question...

Comment: @Pete Becker - that's true.  My comment was about explaining the case of this particular identifier, not reserved identifiers more generally.

Comment: Updated link to "chrono_io.h" which does only streaming out of durations and is much simplified:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/chrono_io.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant)'s original implementation of `chrono_io` uses llvm/libc++ specific features like `__scan_keyword`.

If you plan to use it on another compiler, which it seems like you do, take a look at [Boost's implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/chrono/chrono_io.hpp) of the library. It is meant to be compatible with more compilers.

To do this, llvm-specific functions were removed or replaced. You can even find the reimplementation of the offending [`scan_keyword` here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/chrono/detail/scan_keyword.hpp).